# How to download stickers in Facebook graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk

I have studied Facebook API documentation and looked up other resources. It seems Facebook API does not provide a way to download stickers in a message thread. Is there any way I can retrieve stickers from Facebook threads?

If there is no way of downloading stickers available to developers, then my question is how is the Facebook messenger app able to do it?

Comment: Why did my question get downvoted? Which guidelines does it violate?

Comment: There is no public API for downloading stickers.

Comment: I'm just curious if these stickers are ok for commercial use - can I use them in my own projects?  I have integrated the Facebook in my app so I would hope so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by WizKid (a FB employee) there is no public API available for getting stickers. The Facebook messenger app uses an internal API.

Answer (score 1):

In Facebook messages, sticker link can be found in `{message-id}/shares/link`.

Link to API reference:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.10/message/shares

Answer (score 0):

Stickers can now be pulled through the "attachment" field on a comment:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.8/comment

The graph will include attachment.url which can be used as an image source.